# Exporting ArcMap Animation with Transparent Background?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, animation, transparency-opacity

Because ArcMap (10.3.1) only exports animations at a screenshot level (not high resolution, at all), I would like to export a high-res basemap as a standalone image. It would then be ideal to **export just animated points with a transparent background over top of the static map**. This is an issue because ArcMap to my knowledge does not support PNG in the "export animation as sequential images" window (only BMP and JPEG).

Am I missing something here? Or is there a workaround to allow transparency in a BMP format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ArcMap, there is no way I know of to bump up the resolution. For "transparency" of background, you could make the background a bright color, and then in Photoshop, replace the color with transparency and export to PNG. That could be a lot of work depending on how many photos you have. There might be a way to [automate that process](http://www.howtogeek.com/166973/how-to-automate-your-workflow-in-adobe-photoshop/) in Photoshop, depending on how savvy you are with Photoshop.

That being said, **with ArcGIS Pro, .PNG is an option in File Export Settings** for animations. Is ArcGIS Pro an option? Check it out here:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/animation/export-an-animation.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DA51FCE86592461A8B78090296B2A665

Comment: ArcGIS Pro would be an option. Very good link too. Much appreciated.